# Object has no method 'appendChild'

Tags: javascript

When I send a div to a function which creates content to a document fragment it provides me this error when I append the fragment to the div.

```
Object column_left has no method 'appendChild' '
```

This is my code:

```
function progress_bar(parent_div){      
    var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
    var d = document.createElement('div');
        d.className = 'progress_bg';
        d.style.width = '90%';
    frag.appendChild(d);
    parent_div.appendChild(frag);
}
```

The function is called like this:

```
var d = document.getElementById('column_left');
progress_bar(d);
```

Does any one know why i cannot append like this?

Comment: can you provide your HTML markup as well?

Comment: @Zhanger do you mean the content of the CSS class `progress_bg` ?

Comment: sorry, I didn't realize you were generating the DOM out of nothing lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you call `progress_bar(d)`, `#column_left` doesn't exist (yet) so `d` is undefined. Since you're passing in an `undefined` value into progress_bar you can't call appendChild on it.

In order to fix this, you either have to create `#column_left` first, or pick a pre-existing element like `document.body`.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/wwtyU/) is a JSFiddle with the code cleaned up, I made it so it appends to the document's body instead and also sets the inner content something is actually rendered.

If you wanted to do it on `#column_left`, it would be something like this:

```
var el = document.createElement('div');
el.id = 'column_left';
document.body.appendChild(el);
progress_bar(el);
```